# Google app engine datastore read by entity wise

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We have application in google appengine. In appengine app dashbord showing millions of reads in entire app. We are unable to find which kind taking more reads. Is there a way to check per kind reads on daily basis.

We checked the appstats feature. But it is showing per url stats. But we need entity wise reads count.

Please give us a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available on appengine.  As you have noted, only entity total reads are available, and per url request statistics.  If you really need access to this sort of data, you could try one of the following:

1) Implement a log-based system, then later run an analysis on these logs.  For instance, everytime you read from an entity, write a log using logging.info("Read from User Entities").

2) Analyze each endpoint to estimate the number of queries by type each request would entail, and then calculate read queries given the number of requests at that URL.  Obviously, this won't be exact, but it should serve as some sort of estimate.